# How can select 2 records for each id from a table.?

Tags: sql-server

How to select two records from multiple records first where the date field is minimum and second where the date field is maximum. 
I will try to explain you in brief:-  I have a records_history table where there can be multiple records for one Employee. I want to select only two records for one employee based on max and minimum date . How can i achieve this?
Currently what is done for this scenario is first select all records from Employee then stored it into a temp table the apply cursor for the temp table and get the distinct employee record and then they are selecting the max and min data records from the temp table. but it is taking to much time for processing.
Please suggest a way out for this problem.?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you want max and min value for one column based on employee ID.

```
Select max(column_name) as 'Max', min(column_name) as 'Mini' from table_name group by EmployeeID having EmployeeID='EmployeeID'
```

Please accept the answer if it helps